# Hive: how to retrieve data by row timestamp

Tags: hbase, hive

I am using hive to run select queries on HBase tables.

I want to retrieve all rows where with timestamp value lower then X.

My question is how to created select query like this (should I need to create the Hive table in particular way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamp is an attribute associated with a column value.  Unless Hive has a specific convention called out in the documentation to make column timestamps explicitly available, I doubt you can access the timestamp information from Hive.

In HBase, you can construct a scan and add a filter condition for the timestamp.  There is a example that you can base such a filter off in the code:
/hbase/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/TimestampsFilter.java

Note: you have to make sure that your code is in the classpath of every regionserver before this will work. Which implies that you will have to restart your regionservers.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Quora thread](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-date-time-datetime-columns-in-Hive), two timestamp functions [are available in Hive 0.8](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions):

`from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, string timezone)`

`to_utc_timestamp(timestamp, string timezone)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the OP is seeking the ability to select rows from a table whose create timestamp matches a condition.
AFAIK, Hive does not expose this.
The two functions above are for converting a given timestamp values (which are interpreted as UTC) to and from a given timezones.